# pandas - create new column based off of 'next' row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   date      country   
   6/1/18    USA
   6/1/18    BEL
   6/4/18    USA
   6/5/18    BEL
   6/6/18    USA
```

I want to create a column that tells you what the next date for the corresponding country is. You can assume the dates are ordered if it helps. If the date is the last date for the country, you can fill in next date with the same date or a null value.

```
   date      country   next_date
   6/1/18    USA       6/4/18
   6/1/18    BEL       6/5/18
   6/4/18    USA       6/6/18
   6/5/18    BEL       6/5/18
   6/6/18    USA       6/6/18
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use **`groupby`** and **`shift`** to fill in the next available value, however, this will leave rows without a next available date as **`NaN`**:

```
df.assign(ndate=df.groupby('country').date.shift(-1))
```

```
     date country   ndate
0  6/1/18     USA  6/4/18
1  6/1/18     BEL  6/5/18
2  6/4/18     USA  6/6/18
3  6/5/18     BEL     NaN
4  6/6/18     USA     NaN
```

If you would like to fill in these values with the last seen date, you may simply **`fillna`** with your **`date`** column:

```
df.assign(ndate=df.groupby('country').date.shift(-1)).fillna({'ndate': df.date})
```

```
     date country   ndate
0  6/1/18     USA  6/4/18
1  6/1/18     BEL  6/5/18
2  6/4/18     USA  6/6/18
3  6/5/18     BEL  6/5/18
4  6/6/18     USA  6/6/18
```

Comment: Did you change your first answer that used ffill()?

Comment: Yes, there's really no reason to ffill when it's the equivalent of just using the same value as the `date` column

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks then.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html).  I have opted to leave the final dates as NaN values.

```
>>> df.assign(next_date=df.groupby('country')['date'].transform(
                  lambda group: group.shift(-1)))
     date country next_date
0  6/1/18     USA    6/4/18
1  6/1/18     BEL    6/5/18
2  6/4/18     USA    6/6/18
3  6/5/18     BEL       NaN
4  6/6/18     USA       NaN
```